# Display transactions from a bakery

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

In kaggle.com there is a  BreadBasket_DMS.csv file which dataset of transactions from a bakery. Using this data set, I want to calculate the the top-10 sold items for breakfast, lunch, and dinner. I want to display the code I have written as the table below. I would be very grateful if you could help.

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
from datetime import datetime
data = pd.read_csv("BreadBasket_DMS.csv")
def add_datetime_features(data):
    # 6-11: breakfast; 11-15: lunch;  15-20: dinner
    data['Time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Time']).time
    hour = data['Time'].apply(lambda ts: ts.hour)
    data['Hour'],data['Time_Of_Day'] = hour,hour
    data['Time_Of_Day'].replace([i for i in range(5,12)], 'breakfast',inplace=True)
    data['Time_Of_Day'].replace([i for i in range(12,16)], 'lunch',inplace=True)
    data['Time_Of_Day'].replace([i for i in range(16,21)], 'dinner',inplace=True)
    data.drop('Time',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

[image: display the this table format]

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

As far as I see you already have a column `Time_Of_Day` and a column `item`.

So, assuming a dummy dataframe with the same columns:

```
In[]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Time_Of_Day': ['breakfast', 'breakfast', 'breakfast', 'lunch', 'lunch', 'lunch'], 'item': ['coffee', 'coffee', 'bread', 'pastry', 'pastry', 'coffee']})
In[]: df
Out[]:
  Time_Of_Day    item
0   breakfast  coffee
1   breakfast  coffee
2   breakfast   bread
3       lunch  pastry
4       lunch  pastry
5       lunch  coffee
```

In that case, a groupby will get you very close:

```
In[]: counts = df.groupby(['Time_Of_Day', 'item']).size()
In[]: counts
Out[]:
Time_Of_Day  item  
breakfast    bread     1
             coffee    2
lunch        coffee    1
             pastry    2
dtype: int64
```

You now have a hierarchical index. You can get the amount of breads sold at breakfast like this:

```
In[]: counts['breakfast']['bread']
Out[]: 1
```

You can now find the top 10 items sold during breakfast for instance:

```
In[]: counts['breakfast'].sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[]: 
item
coffee    2
bread     1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

But more interesting, you can use pandas `rank` function to compute the rank of each count *within* the time of the day:

```
In[]: output = pd.DataFrame({'counts': counts})
In[]: output.reset_index(inplace=True)
In[]: output['rank'] = output.groupby('Time_Of_Day')['counts'].rank(method='first')
In[]: output
Out[]:
  Time_Of_Day    item  counts  rank
0   breakfast   bread       1   1.0
1   breakfast  coffee       2   2.0
2       lunch  coffee       1   1.0
3       lunch  pastry       2   2.0
```

The `rank` column now gives you the position of the item within the same time of the day. So here, `bread` is sold most during `breakfast` (it has rank 1) and `coffee` is most sold during `lunch`.

You can sort by rank to get the top items sold:

```
In[]: output.sort_values(by='rank')
Out[]:
  Time_Of_Day    item  counts  rank
0   breakfast   bread       1   1.0
2       lunch  coffee       1   1.0
1   breakfast  coffee       2   2.0
3       lunch  pastry       2   2.0
```

As said, this is a partial answer. I don't manage to transform this exactly into the format you request. It requires some trickery with pandas dataframe indexes. But I hope this already helps.

Comment: yes, to get the desired output format, it may use set_index, unstack, and swaplevel when every group with the same index rank 0~9.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the time ranges you defined do not cover the full domain. Second, here is a way to do this without reaching for `pandas` and without having to store the entire underlying data in memory. Adjust formatting of the output to taste.

```py
import heapq
import sys

sales = {}

class Sale:
    @staticmethod
    def time_of_day(tm):
        hr = int(tm.split(':')[0])
        if hr in range(6, 11):
            return 'breakfast'
        if hr in range(11, 15):
            return 'lunch'
        if hr in range(15, 20):
            return 'dinner'
        return 'munchies'

    def __init__(self, line):
        dt, tm, txn, item = line.rstrip().split(',')
        self.dt = dt
        self.tm = tm
        self.txn = txn
        self.item = item.lower()
        self.time_of_day = Sale.time_of_day(self.tm)

def is_skippable(item):
    return (item == 'adjustment') or (item == 'none')

def load_sales(fh):
    # skip header
    fh.readline()

    sales = {
        'breakfast': {},
        'lunch': {},
        'dinner': {},
        'munchies': {},
    }

    for line in fh:
        sale = Sale(line)
        if is_skippable(sale.item):
            continue

        item = sale.item
        tod = sale.time_of_day

        sales[tod][item] = sales[tod].get(item, 0) + 1

    return sales

def main():
    sales = load_sales(sys.stdin)
    sep = "===================="
    for tod in sales:
        top10 = heapq.nlargest(10, sales[tod].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        print(tod)
        print(sep)
        print("\n".join(list(map(lambda x: ":\t".join([x[0], str(x[1])]), top10))))
        print(sep, "\n\n")

main()
```

Sample output:

```
breakfast
====================
coffee: 1615
bread:  1081
pastry: 453
medialuna:      294
tea:    280
toast:  149
hot chocolate:  141
farm house:     132
cake:   131
cookies:        128
====================


lunch
====================
coffee: 2929
bread:  1683
tea:    773
sandwich:       620
cake:   566
pastry: 345
soup:   281
hot chocolate:  266
cookies:        255
medialuna:      247
====================


dinner
====================
coffee: 926
bread:  560
tea:    382
cake:   328
hot chocolate:  181
cookies:        157
alfajores:      128
sandwich:       109
brownie:        99
juice:  84
====================


munchies
====================
postcard:       7
vegan feast:    7
tshirt: 5
pintxos:        4
hot chocolate:  2
valentine's card:       2
dulce de leche: 1
fudge:  1
vegan mincepie: 1
coke:   1
====================
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and help sir. I want to display that I have added the code I wrote, as in the table.

Comment: Well, once you have the desired information, you can print it any which way you want. However, I am going to note that your display shows 'NONE' items among the top 10 and displays integers as floating point numbers.